# Rails 3: Possible to order with a junction-table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, junction-table

I have a nested form which creates many locations for each post. Each location can also be used in multiple posts.

E.g. Post 1 may have Location1, Location2 and Location3

AND  Post 2 may have Location1, Location4 and Location5

I want these locations to be ordered within the posts in the same order that they were added. I assume the easiest way to do this is to add an 'order' column to the joining table (Posts_Locations) however i'm not sure how to set this up or define `:order_by` in my controller. Should I do this with directly with SQL?

Any suggestions? Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a simple join table and the `has_and_belongs_to_many` for both Post and Location, you may want to make the posts_locations table a model in its own right, joining the two using `has_many :through`.  This is well described [here in this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Bonus hint: when you're adding the new column, change the model, and thus join table name to something singular, like PostLocation which will result in a table name `post_locations` ... or perhaps something more descriptive.  Also, don't use the word "order" for this field, since it's a keyword in both rails and SQL.  Maybe call it "display_order"?

Then in the PostLocation model you might create a scope, or even a default scope that defines the proper order., e.g. `scope :sorted, order("display_order DESC")`

The other question I might ask: is it really the case that the order of the Posts is linked to whichever location and vice-versa?

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used default_scope, for anyone interested. Many Thanks @tharrison

Comment: Cool!  Many people frown on `default_scope` when it's used to filter, as in with `where(:active => true)`, but in my view, setting a default order is a perfect use.  Check out `unscoped` just so you know it's there if you ever want to change the order.